# 'set' object has no attribute 'setdefault'. Error in scraping data using using Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to hit a website using python Requests, but it's giving me error.

```
import requests 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36'}
URL = ""
PROXY = {'https://surfproxy.de.db.com:8080' }
response = requests.get(URL , proxies = PROXY, headers: headers)
```

The error logs:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/vermanjb/JiraScrapping.py', wdir='C:/Users/vermanjb')
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 88, in execfile
>       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/vermanjb/JiraScrapping.py", line 12, in 
>       response = requests.get(URL , proxies = PROXY)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 67, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 53, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in
>   request
>       prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 619, in
>   merge_environment_settings
>       proxies.setdefault(k, v)
>
> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Comment: Why are you using a set as the value of `proxies`?

Comment: `PROXY` needs to be a dictionary not a set

Comment: Change to `PROXY = {'https': https://surfproxy.de.db.com:8080' }`. Also `headers: headers`? Shouldn't this be `headers=headers`?

Comment: Thanks. But i'm getting aniother error. ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 notresolvable',)))      But i'm able to ping this website from CMD using the same proxy

Comment: this is a totally different issue, and it's a system issue not a programming one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems you should fix:

1. The `proxies` parameter [should be a dict](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies), not a set.
2. You have a syntax error in your `headers` parameter.

Try this instead:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0...'}
url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/'
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://surfproxy.de.db.com:8080',
    'https': 'http://surfproxy.de.db.com:8080'
}
response = requests.get(url , proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
```